Cannot get Ubuntu to boot on a Latitude 5490
Hi trying to install Ubuntu on a latitude 5490. It boots from a live USB but I cannot get it to boot from the hard disk. I have checked out this no bootable devices dell laptop
I note that the Dell Latitude is not listed as ubuntu certified Ubuntu certified
Is it worth my persisting or is it a waste of time trying to get Ubuntu onto this device? I have done a lot of research around UEFI installation but I am not getting this to work with anything except a live USB.

I cannot get it to boot from the hard disk - Did you install Ubuntu? Did you install the bootloader in the same disk where Ubuntu was installed? Does UEFI show the hard disk as a boot device?

You'll need to provide details; as currently a user-procedural error is most likely, given you've not provided us anything else. We don't know what Ubuntu product you downloaded, if its appropriate for your hardware, if you checked it as being valid, wrote to install media that was bootable on your device; that write of ISO was valid (did you check it?) etc.. I've installed Ubuntu one old BIOS devices, plus uEFI & Secure-boot enabled uEFI devices; but you've not indicated anything beyond Ubuntu which is available for many architectures, many products, many releases etc

Hi, apologies - it was ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso

I have now succeeded. I found a video by Dr David Yip which explained how to configure the Dell's settings A Clean Install of Linux Ubuntu 20.04 (Dell UEFI BIOS with Secure Boot and MOK)
The issue I was having was it did not let me check / uncheck items (such as enable legacy option ROMs) on the UEFI set up. It took a number of attempts going to Advanced boot, Secure boot and Boot sequence to get the right combination - and I had to set up a new boot option for ubuntu but that did the trick. Apologies as usual for my ineptitude and inability to explain the issue I was having. I was concerned that the Dell 5490 was not on the ubuntu certified list - but it works - it was a question of getting the boot options in the correct mode and frustratingly I had to skip between pages and use trial and error until it finally worked. Thanks Archisman Panigrahi and guiverc for helping - you set me on the right path.

Good to see you got it set up, but it would be more helpful to others if you included the items you changed to make it work, since links may disappear in the future.

I list the steps I did below.

On another machine, Download the ISO – make a bootable USB with MKUSB MKUSB Wiki
Boot up the computer for Ubuntu installation
Hit F2 to get to boot menu
go to advanced boot options
Make sure Enable Legacy Roms is unchecked. Press Apply button
Go to Secure boot page – make sure secure boot is enabled. Press Apply button
Then go to boot sequence – Check UEFI as a Boot List Option
Click add boot option.
Call new boot option ubuntu. Check & Apply.
Exit.
Insert the bootable USB, start the installation from the USB as usual.

When I looked at the boot sequence post installation Linux Firmware Updater was added as to the boot sequence - presumably as part of the installation process.
